# Updating the Tkinter button error with code structure Explanation required

Tags: python

So I'm currently teaching myself python, and I am developing a simple GUI restaurant menu. But I came across an error I'm hoping someone could explain, I've solved it by doing `self.total_button` by option, rather than putting the options in parentheses (like I did for the button above it), but the only thing I have changed is that and the program runs with no errors.

The line in the `total` method `self.total_button["text"] = "Total £"+ str(self.cash_total)` only works when I declare `self.total_button` the way I do, if I declare each option in parentheses it states a `Nonetype' object does not support item assignment`.

Does layout matter with buttons in tkinter when updating them later in a program?

```
#Order Up!
#A Simple GUI program, that presents a simple restaurant menu.
#It lists items, and prices.
#Let the user select different items and then show the user the total bill.

from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """Create a GUI application."""
    def __init__(self, master):
        """Initialises the frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.cash_total = 0

        self.total_list = []
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        """Creates the widgets that creates the menu ordering systems"""
        #Create a instruction label
        Label(self,
              text = "Click the desired buttons to order something"
              ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = N)

        #Create Burger button
        Button(self,
               text = "Hamburger no bun",
               command = self.hamburger_no_bun
               ).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
        #Creates a total button
        #Super weird bug have to set it out like this so i can use the total method later.
        self.total_button = Button(self)
        self.total_button["text"] = "Total: £"
        self.total_button["command"] = self.total
        self.total_button.grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W)

        #Create Text Box to show current order
        self.order_txt = Text (self, width = 100, height = 8, wrap = WORD)
        self.order_txt.grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = W)



    def hamburger_no_bun(self):
        """Creates a hamburger tuple to be added to the list."""
        self.hamburger_no_bun = ("Hamburger no bun, £", 2.95)
        self.total_list.append(self.hamburger_no_bun)
        self.order_txt.insert(0.2, str(self.hamburger_no_bun))

    def total(self):
        #The affected method
        """Adds the total amount due taken from the total_list"""
        for i in self.total_list:
            self.cash_total += i[1]
        print(self.cash_total)
        self.total_button["text"] = "Total £"+ str(self.cash_total)
        self.cash_total = 0

#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Order Up! - A Restaurant Menu GUI")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wrote code like this

```
self.total_button = Button(self, self, text="Total: £", command=self.total).grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W)
```

You may be suprised to learn that `self.total_button` now holds the value `None`. This is because it is holding the return value of the `grid` method of the `Button` not the button reference itself.

Later when you try to use `self.total_button` it will throw an exception, because the value is `None` and `None` has no attribute `"Text"`.

To resolve the issue you must correctly capture the reference to the button and to do this split the line creating and setting up the button into two lines.

```
self.total_button = Button(self, text="Total: £", command=self.total)
self.total_button.grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W)
```

Now you have a correct reference to the button, that will be usable later in the `total` method.

Comment: That is an excellent answer @paul-rooney thank you very much! For clarifying it for me. I thought it was adding a none type but I wasn't sure how. You were right about how I added it initially.